# Identifying the Closure and Interior

Tags: general-topology

Let $$A = \left\lbrace\left.\frac{1}{n^{2}+1} \ \right| \ n\in \mathbb{N}\right\rbrace = \left\lbrace \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{17}, \frac{1}{26} ,\dotsc\right\rbrace \subset\mathbb{R}.$$ Identify the closure $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and the interior $\operatorname{Int}(A)$ with respect to the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$.

Anyone have any idea how to do this cause I am lost
Btw d is just the standard metric on R ie d(x,y)= |x-y|

Comment: You haven't told us what $d$ means, but anyway you should start by making sure you know what *closure* and *interior* mean. Are there any example where you are able to work out the interior and the closure? can you do it for, say, the half-open interval $(0,1]$?

Comment: I have now added d

Comment: Good. Now, what about the rest of what I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cl(A)** is **A** union its limit points. So what is

(lim_{n \to infty} \frac{1}{1+n^{2}}) ?

The interior is the union of all open subsets of **A**. Can you draw an open interval around any point in **A** that only contains points in **A**?